# dompdf 0.8.2 pdf template with variable / code php

Tags: dompdf

I have a problem with dompdf in PHP, in my template file dompdf does not execute my `<?php ?>` code. Do you have any ideas?

### Template.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
      BEFORE
      <?php echo "PHP CODE"; ?>
     AFTER
   <?php echo $var1; ?>
```

### PHP code

```
<?php

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/html5lib/Parser.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Autoloader.php';
Dompdf\Autoloader::register();
$var1 = "TEST1";
var_dump($var1);

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('isPhpEnabled', TRUE);
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
    $dompdf->loadHtml( file_get_contents(dirname(__DIR__) . '\template.php') );
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents(dirname(__DIR__) . '/data/' .'Output.pdf', $output);
```

### PDF output

BEFORE  AFTER

....

### Info

dompdf/dompdf version ^0.8.2

PHP 7.2.12

Thanks C,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `file_get_contents` it only takes the content of a file, it do not evaluate the content of the file (fo ex: `<?php code?>`).

I have to add to my code a buffering mecanics:

```
ob_start();
include $template;
$contents = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf->loadHtml($contents);
```

C